# When to use -std=c11 while compiling a C source code using ubunto

Tags: c, ubuntu

I am trying to compile a C source code to a machine code using an ubunto terminal
My tutor instruction was to use the following command:

```
running clang myprogramm.c -std=c11
```

Why shall I use the keyword -std=c11 and what is the difference to using just

```
clang myprogramm.c
```

Comment: As the documentation tells you, it sets the used language standard to version C11. So you have to use it when you use features that were added in that version of the standard

Comment: Awesome! Thank you UnholySheep for the quick answer!

Comment: Standard compile options should include `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` (to enable warnings, consider `-Wshadow` as well), then `-std=c11` for the library standard and `-Ofast` or `-O3` for optimization level. There is no need in 2020 to use a coding standard below `c11` unless you are maintaining an old codebase that hasn't yet been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Using `std=` options is required by your tutor (I'm divinig her motives, I'm particularly good at this!) because she wants to make sure you stay away from all those nifty Clang features that turn the accepted language from C to *A LANGUAGE SUPERFICIALLY LOOKING LIKE C BUT ACTUALLY A DIFFERENT LANGUAGE NOT SUPPORTED BY OTHER C COMPILERS*.

That is more than just additional library functions. It include syntax changes that break the grammar of Standard C, as defined by ISO. A grasshopper should not use these while learning. Using `-std=c11` makes sure Clang either warns about or even rejects, with an error, such constructs.

Answer (score 0):

When to specify the standard? Whenever you use the compiler. It is never a good idea to let the compiler just use whatever it wants.

If someone tries to use a compiler that is too old, then they will get a warning or error, and they will understand why the compile fails.

If a code contributor (maybe even yourself!) tries to add code using features that are too new, their code will be rejected. That's very important if you intend to keep compatibility with an older standard.

By explicitly stating the standard, using new features or extensions are a choice and don't happen by accident.